# Mecanismo Licenciamiento de Genexus

Tags: genexus, licencias

Actualmente tengo contratado el plan Genexus for ISV que incluye una licencia para el IDE y los generadores .NET, Java, Ruby y SD. Este plan lo comencé cuando Genexus Evolution 3 era la versión más reciente.

Con el advenimiento de Genexus 15 (actualmente en versión RC) como versión más reciente quisiera saber si al instalar las licencias para GX 15 me dejará de funcionar la IDE (y generadores) de Genexus Evolution 3 o si ambas funcionarán en paralelo.

Comment: Si, las licencias GeneXus son "**retrocompatibles**" o sea sirven anteriores para todas las versiones del producto de la licencia comprada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, efectivamente puedes instalar las licencias de GeneXus 15 y vas a poder trabajar en paralelo tanto con la versión Evolution 3 como con la 15.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún enlace?

Comment: La versión 15 de GeneXus estará disponible luego de su liberación durante el próximo encuentro GeneXus los días 26 al 28 de Setiembre. El setup estará disponible en https://www.genexus.com/developers/DownloadCenter?es,,, donde actualmente se puede descargar la versión Evolution 3.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo instalar proteccion server,y puedes tener las licencias separadas, y asi mantienes tus versiones o tener un servidor de licencias, que las usando segun version

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/341690)